# Facebook graph api : Param score must be an integer

Tags: facebook-graph-api, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

I am using sdk version 7.4 when i post the score i get this error

score posted to the fb{"error":{"message":"(#100) Param score must be an integer","type":"OAuthException","code":100,"fbtrace_id":"ElqTb0bxXz4"}}

Concerned Code

```
var scoreData = new Dictionary<string ,string> ();
    scoreData ["score"] = UnityEngine.Random.Range (10f, 500f).ToString();
    FB.API("/me/scores?fields=",HttpMethod.POST,delegate(IGraphResult result){
    Debug.Log("score posted to the fb"+result.RawResult.ToString());


    },scoreData);
```

Any Suggestion or answer is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var scoreData = new Dictionary<string ,int> ();
    scoreData ["score"] = UnityEngine.Random.Range (10, 500);
    FB.API("/me/scores?fields=",HttpMethod.POST,delegate(IGraphResult result){
    Debug.Log("score posted to the fb"+result.RawResult.ToString());


    },scoreData);
```

Comment: haven't tried it, just guessing out of the error message

Comment: argument `#4' cannot convert `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,int>' expression to type `UnityEngine.WWWForm'

Comment: oh ok, then try this:
var scoreData = new Dictionary<string ,string> ();
    scoreData ["score"] = UnityEngine.Random.Range (10, 500).ToString();

Comment: the only difference is that Random(10f, 500f) might return 395.46 which is not integer while Random(10, 500) will only give you integers

Comment: Ok that seems to work just gives me error Requires extended permission

Answer (score 0):

I had this same error and I fixed it today.

The issue is **I was not converting an integer class to string.**
The problem could be your scores are saved as float, and when you convert them ToString they convert as 2.00, thus, not being an int as Facebook requests.

I created a variable:

```
int intScore = (int)myScore.
```

And then just added it to my dict.

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
dict["score"] = myScore.ToString;
```

That worked flawlessly.